# How to disable separator line focus when I scroll the list view?

Tags: android, listview, textview, divider

I used a listview for inserting items and a text view for seperating each item in that list.

```
   <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:divider="@null"
     />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/line_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/issueno"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@color/line_color"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

It works fine, But when i see in Emulator first line looking as 2dp height , second line with 1dp height and Third line again looks ad 2dp height, It repeats when i scroll that list view.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to remove line

```
android:divider="@null"
```

if you want to change its color or size then use this

```
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
android:dividerHeight="3dp"
```

Comment: Sorry Kulakarni garu, Thats not problem When I scrolls listview divider lines are focused

Comment: can you post your output image?

Comment: I dont have more reputation, pls send me mail id I will send that screenshots

Comment: put your screenshot on http://prnt.sc/ as it doesnt require registration and share link here

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your java code

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
listView.setDividerHeight(0);
```

or

Do this in ur xml

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:divider="#EAEAEA"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
```

Comment: if u r using listview means the above code will remove that divider line

Comment: Some where u r specifying the divider height pls check ur code. u should give divider height as 0.

Comment: try this in on resume    getListView().setDividerHeight(0);
getListView().setDivider(null);